# A Dipole in an External Electric Field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole

We can derive that, the potential energy of a dipole in an external electric field is
$$U=-\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{E}$$
And Work done by the field on the dipole is
$$W=\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{E}$$
Here, we use $U=-W$. All of my physics books tell the reason for $U=-W$ is that comes analogously from gravitational potential energy. I need a rigorous description in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep on mind the position chosen for the zero of potential energy; namely when the electric dipole vector (pointing from negative to positive charge) is at $90^o$ the the E field.  The E field does positive work (as torque times change in angle) to take the dipole to its position of maximum negative potential in line with the field. An external torque would be needed to rotate the dipole from that position to one with a zero or positive potential energy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need gravitational potential energy, to defined potential energy. Authors do that because gravity is easy to understand (and has lots of daily examples).

First, let's construct a concept for How we define [Potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy).

If a particle moves from a point $\mathbf{r}_a$ to point $\mathbf{r}_b$ under the influence of force $\mathbf{F}$, then [Work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)) done by the force is defined as
$$W_{ba}=\oint_\mathbf{r_a}^\mathbf{r_b}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$$
where integral is line integral.

Now if the force is conservative then work done by this force will be given by
$$\oint_\mathbf{r_a}^\mathbf{r_b}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\mathcal{function \ of }(\mathbf{r}_b)-\mathcal{function \ of }(\mathbf{r}_a)$$]]

$$\oint_\mathbf{r_a}^\mathbf{r_b}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=-U(\mathbf{r_b})+U(\mathbf{r_a})$$
where $U(\mathbf{r})$ is a function, defined by the above expression, known as
the potential energy function (reason for negative sign will become clear as we go along).

---

This section explain why it's called potential energy.

Next from work-energy theorem

$$W_{ba}=K_b-K_a$$

Thus for coservative forces
$$K_b-K_a=-U(\mathbf{r_b})+U(\mathbf{r_a})$$
or
$$K_a+U(\mathbf{r_a})=K_a+U(\mathbf{r_b})=E$$

$E$ is called the total mechanical energy of the particle.

---

That's the reason we define the potential energy as
$$W_{ba}=-U(\mathbf{r_b})+U(\mathbf{r_a})$$

If we consider the other point at infinite (where the effect of most force is neligble) then we can take potential energy to be zero at infinite so that We can define potential energy as work done by the particle in travelling from infinite to that point.

Comment: Great Explanation.You just made a simple mistake.E=K(b)+U(rb)